# Multiple definition of a function error, even when using #if guard clauses

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple UTIL.h file contain aplusb(int, int) function for my C++ project. However I cannot compile and the error message is about multiple definition of `aplusb(int, int)'. Would you please help me correct the error or give me some hints?

I attach here my project for your detail reference.

File UTIL.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

int aplusb(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

#endif /* UTIL_H_ */
```

File ClassA.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H_
#define CLASSA_H_

class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA();
    virtual ~ClassA();
private:
    int sum;
};

#endif /* CLASSA_H_ */
```

File ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "UTIL.h"

ClassA::ClassA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    sum = aplusb(3,5);

}

ClassA::~ClassA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

File ClassB.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H_
#define CLASSB_H_

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB();
    virtual ~ClassB();
private:
    int sum;
};

#endif /* CLASSB_H_ */
```

File ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "UTIL.h"

ClassB::ClassB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    sum = aplusb(5,6);
}

ClassB::~ClassB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Compile error message

```
ClassB.o: In function `aplusb(int, int)':
/home/vtvan/Desktop/workspace/commonfunc/UTIL.h:11: multiple definition of `aplusb(int, int)'
ClassA.o:/home/vtvan/Desktop/workspace/commonfunc/UTIL.h:11: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [commonfunc] Error 1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First variant - use `inline` specifier

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

inline int aplusb(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

#endif /* UTIL_H_ */
```

Second variant - write definition in `.cpp` file.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the second variant would be "right", and the first one not. What would be the problems of inlining this function ?

Comment: But why dont the header guards work in this case? I thought that header guards causes the code executed only once. This would, in this case create the "int aplusb(int,int)" function definition only once. I'm confused..

Comment: @lukasz1985 one declaration. but not one definition.

Answer (score 5):

You created the function aplusb in your include file. This means that for every file you include it to, a public function aplusb will be created, resulting in a name clash.

If the function should be inline, then mark it so. If the function should be a template, then mark it so. If the function should be as you wrote it, put it in a cpp file and just keep the protoype in the h file.

```
.h
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

int aplusb(int a, int b);

#endif

.cpp
int aplusb(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your aplusb function in the header file, and provide the definition in a cpp file. Something like

util.h:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

int aplusb(int, int);

#endif /* UTIL_H_ */
```

The error message is telling you that each time that you include the util.h file, you are re-defining the function, which is exactly what you are doing :-) This is a violation of the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (one-definition-rule), which states that the definition (of a function, in this case) must be unique. Otherwise the compiler would be unable to choose between the alternatives (even if, like in this case, they happen to be equal).

Note that templates complicate the matter a bit (in short, because a template is not a definition until instatiated).

Answer (score 0):

Header files are not intended to have actual functions in them (certain C++ aspects such as templates not withstanding). General practice in your case would have you changing your UTIL.H to just prototyping the function (`int aplusb(int a, int b);`) and moving its implementation to a source file.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to put functions in header files, so long as you mark them inline.

Comment: My statement _such as templates not withstanding_ was not intended to be exhaustive of all of the cases where it's ok to put functions in header files.

Comment: But it happens that templates have nothing to do with the case at hand, while there is a perfectly valid way to define this function in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a Util struct where every function is declared static. You can then access every function using `Util::<function name>`

File UTIL.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

struct Util{
    static int aplusb(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

#endif /* UTIL_H_ */
```

File ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "UTIL.h"

ClassA::ClassA() {
    sum = Util::aplusb(3,5);
}

ClassA::~ClassA() {
}
```

File ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "UTIL.h"

ClassB::ClassB() {
    sum = Util::aplusb(5,6);
}

ClassB::~ClassB() {
}
```