# Why am I getting a 'multiple definition' error? how do i fix it?

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

command given by terminal:

> g++ main.cpp test.cpp

Error message:

> /tmp/ccvgRjlI.o: In function `test2()': 
> test.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple
>   definition of `test2()'
>   /tmp/ccGvwiUE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   main.cpp

Source code:

```
#include "test.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

test.hpp

```
#ifndef _TEST_HPP_
#define _TEST_HPP_

#include <iostream>

void test();
void test2() { std::cerr << "test2" << std::endl; }

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

void test() { cerr << "test" << endl; }
```

btw the following compiles fine:

> g++ main.cpp

Comment: Add the `inline` keyword before test2 to get around the one definition rule.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but names like `_TEST_HPP_` are reserved in C++. Lose the leading underscore.

Comment: @latedeveloper would TEST_HPP be fine?

Comment: @lost Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple definition of a function error, even when using #if guard clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396130/multiple-definition-of-a-function-error-even-when-using-if-guard-clauses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header `test.hpp` is included in two compilation  units. The first one is the compilation unit `main.cpp` and the second one is the compilation unit `test.cpp`.

Functions by default have external linkage.  This means that functions with the same name and signature denote the same function in different compilation units. They shall be defined once. However in your program the definition of the function `test2` is found in two compilation units and the linker does not know what definition of the function to use.

You could declare the function as an inline function. For example

```
inline void test2() { std::cerr << "test2" << std::endl; }
```

In this case it may be defined in each compilation unit.

Or you can place in the header only the function declaration as you made with the function `test` and define it for example in `test.cpp`.

Another way is to declare the function as having internal linkage. To do this you can define the function in the header either with the keyword static

```
static void test2() { std::cerr << "test2" << std::endl; }
```

or place it in unnamed name space

```
namespace
{
    void test2() { std::cerr << "test2" << std::endl; }
}
```

In this case each compilation unit will have its own function `test2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `test.hpp` file is included both in `main.cpp`, and `test.cpp`, there are two implementations of `test2` function. So linker produces an error. Move function implementation to the `test.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

You get it because you define (implement) the non-static and non-inline function `test2` inside the header file, and you include the header file in both source files. That means the function will be defined in both [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Answer (score 0):

`main.cpp` and `test.cpp` both include `test.hpp` which *declares* `void test()` and *defines* `void test2()`. By including `test.hpp` in two implementation files, you are making two copies of each definition and declaration. You may declare a function as many times as you want but you can only define it once. Move the body of `void test2()` to a seperate implementation (.cpp) file to resolve the linker error.