# Compile error: Multiple definitions in int main

Tags: c++

I'm working on some homework and I keep getting this error on my professor's testing website:

```
/tmp/ccNzBwVD.o: In function `factorial(int)':
myFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `factorial(int)'
/tmp/ccCqSiuT.o:prog30.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccNzBwVD.o: In function `combination(int, int)':
myFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x52): multiple definition of `combination(int, int)'
/tmp/ccCqSiuT.o:prog30.cpp:(.text+0x52): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My main .cpp file is just some nested for loops and a call upon a prototype:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "myFunctions.h"

#include "myFunctions.cpp"

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int rows;
  cout << "Please Enter The Number of Rows: ";
  cin >> rows;
  cout << rows << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < (rows - i + 1); j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      if (k == 0) {
        cout << "1" << " ";
      } else {
        cout << combination(i, k) << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and the myFunctions.h and myFunctions.cpp are, in order,

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

double factorial( int n );

double combination( int a, int b );

#endif // MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

```
#include "myFunctions.h"
#include <cassert>

double factorial (int n) {
  assert(n >= 0);

  int v = 1;
  while (n > 0) {
    v *= n;
    n--;
  }
  return v;
}


double combination (int a, int b) {

  return (factorial(a) / (factorial(a - b) * factorial(b)));
}
```

What can I do to fix this error? I can't seem to find the solution no matter how many different forums or posts I look at.

Comment: You should never `#include` any `cpp` files.  How are you compiling the program?

Comment: If you are using VSCode you need to follow the instructions how to modify `tasks.json` to build an executable from more than 1 file. The default configuration builds only the active file and is meant for a single source file per executable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a 'multiple definition' error? how do i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597744/why-am-i-getting-a-multiple-definition-error-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of erros occurs if you include .cpp files. Remove the line from your main.cpp and instead link the files together. Easiest way to to so is to give both .cpp to the compiler on cmd.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I give both to the compiler? I'm still new to c++

Comment: I do not know what compiler do you use, but example "g++ main.cpp myFunction.cpp". But if you get more files you should look at something like CMake to automate the build.

Comment: But I am confused about your question because I assume that is the way you compile your code anyway.